# closing a tab > go to the previous edited one

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When closing a tab in sublimetext3, it always brings me back to the left one, whereas on sublimetext2, I was brought to the previously opened-one(not necessarily the left one).

That behavior was really handy in sublimetext2, because it created a kind of history that was easy to go-back through, just by closing tabs successively.

**Is there a setting for that in sublimetext3 ?**

## Steps to reproduce

1. I have 3 tabs open, and the 3rd-one is active:
   [image]
2. I now go and edit the 2nd-one:
   [image]
3. I'm done and decide to close the 2nd-tab:
   [image]

FAIL: i'm not back to the previously edited one: the 3rd-one

Answer (score 2):

There is no setting to do that. However since it can be done with a plugin, and I like to keep my plugin writing skills up to scratch, I've written it for you.

It's called FocusMostRecentTabCloser and the code is both below and in this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mattst/0f50cb0c8a7bbea341829970614bc2a6).

To use it save it as `FocusMostRecentTabCloser.py` somewhere in your `Packages` directory structure and assign keys to the `focus_most_recent_tab_closer` command. e.g.

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+w"], "command": "focus_most_recent_tab_closer"},
```

I have not tested it extensively and it requires Sublime Text 3 build 3024 or later (but that's quite old now).

Reply with a comment if there are any bugs and I'll see what I can do.

```py
# MIT License

import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import time

LAST_FOCUS_TIME_KEY = "focus_most_recent_tab_closer_last_focused_time"

class FocusMostRecentTabCloserCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """ Closes the focused view and focuses the next most recent. """

    def run(self, edit):

        most_recent = []
        target_view = None
        window = self.view.window()

        if not window.views():
            return

        for view in window.views():
            if view.settings().get(LAST_FOCUS_TIME_KEY):
                most_recent.append(view)

        most_recent.sort(key=lambda x: x.settings().get(LAST_FOCUS_TIME_KEY))
        most_recent.reverse()

        # Target the most recent but one view - the most recent view
        # is the one that is currently focused and about to be closed.

        if len(most_recent) > 1:
            target_view = most_recent[1]

        # Switch focus to the target view, this must be done before
        # close() is called or close() will shift focus to the left
        # automatically and that buffer will be activated and muck
        # up the most recently focused times.

        if target_view:
            window.focus_view(target_view)

        self.view.close()

        # If closing a view which requires a save prompt, the close()
        # call above will automatically focus the view which requires
        # the save prompt. The code below makes sure that the correct
        # view gets focused after the save prompt closes.

        if target_view and window.active_view().id() != target_view.id():
            window.focus_view(target_view)

class FocusMostRecentTabCloserListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_activated(self, view):
        """ Stores the time the view is focused in the view's settings. """
        view.settings().set(LAST_FOCUS_TIME_KEY, time.time())
```